# Open a second window while method is running - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, window, freeze

I want to open a new Window, while a method of mine is running, to show that something is being done in the background.

```
// Open second window
Encoder.Encode(imgSource, chooseDestination.Text);
// Close second window
```

EDIT: I want the new window to be shown at all times as long as the methode is running, because the program should only continue when the method is finished.
I only want the new window to appear to show the User that somthing is being done in the background (for example have a progress Bar appear on the new window)

Comment: You don't seem to have asked a question. But if you show() a window then a user could potentially still interact with your original window. If you make progress window modal with showdialog() then that could be a bit of a complication for code you're running from the first window.  Like how's it close the modal window. I suggest you reconsider and use a panel instead. Cover controls in your mainwindow. Set a flag isbusy in mainwindowviewmodel true whilst your process runs and use that to gate all commands. Set it false once you finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should consider using asynchronous programming. This is helpful when you don't want to freeze application components (such as UI) while the application is doing certain tasks.

[Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Comment: I have edited my post so it is easier to understand. The User should not be able to do anything while my Encode Method is running, this is why I want to show a new window only with a progress bar. So the User knows that they must wait.

Comment: `Window2 window = new Window2(); window.Show(); Encoder.Encode(imgSource chooseDestination.Text); window.Close();` Is it something what you are looking for?